# Migration from Classic Content to Content Builder

Tags: migration, content-builder, salesforce-classic, email-studio

With the impending end of support for Classic Content in Email Studio, my company started a migration of all of our 2018 emails a few months ago. We currently develop our emails outside of Salesforce in code editors and use the HTML paste feature to get them into Salesforce. Our emails are heavily AMPscripted so it does not makes sense for us to use the WYSIWYG functions. The migration process is taking forever. We are basically copying html and subject lines from Classic and then pasting them into new emails in Content Builder. There are hundreds of emails to copy and my colleagues and I are wondering if there is another fast way to do this. The Import Wizard has copied all of our supporting images, but it does not allow us to copy over emails. Any helps or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: @adam-spriggs  ?.

Comment: have you got any optimal solution ?

Comment: No solutions have been posted. We have completed the process as outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments:

1. There is a tool called Echo a services team can use to mass migrate emails from classic to Content Builder. It requires a services engagement to do so.
2. The question I'd ask, though, is why are you moving the emails now? There's no requirement to move them as they will continue to send once the end of life for classic emails begins next year.

Comment: In the phase 2 - July 2019, We won't be able to edit the email (based on AMPscript) and that will be a trouble for me.

Comment: FWIW, phase 2 won't be until mid-2020. The end of life won't begin until early next year.

Comment: Try this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_content_and_email_creation_tools.htm&type=5 
They say there that this update is affecting since 2019.

Comment: They have updated to 2020, initially the scope was this year (2019). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used a library to keep synchronized local folders and contents to the classic Content tool. That means that I have a mirror from the remote folders into my local and then from there I update everything I want in my local. Then I run the php script to upload all the updated/new content. The library is this one https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP.

However this tool is not supporting Content Builder. But Content Builder has a good feature as a import button that works very well! It recreates all the contents/folders into the Content Builder. Let's say, it mirrors your content Classic content/folder structure.

So, to avoid doing a forever manual updates, You can use that php library. Will require you a considerable effort to accomplished what You need, but once there no more manual updates needed. Not sure if there's a similar library to interact will Content Builder but if exists obviously this would be used to avoid manual updates as well. That means you need to interact with the [Content API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm).

From my experience I have only 2 dynamic emails based on AmpScript. So might be my approach is not useful for you.